export USD with material collection in maya
I need to export USD from maya with material collection assigned to objects
reading usd-maya documentation, I need exportMaterialCollections and according to this ticket resolved, i dont need to setup materialCollectionsPath argument.
so i tried :
cmds.mayaUSDExport( exportMaterialCollections=True, file=usdFilePath, )
this doesn't work, no collection are created. then :
cmds.mayaUSDExport( materialCollectionsPath='/Mtl', exportMaterialCollections=True, file=usdFilePath, )
same result. i tried many variations, without success. The only step forward i've made is with :
cmds.mayaUSDExport( exportCollectionBasedBindings=True, exportMaterialCollections=True, file=usdFilePath, )
material collections is created with the addition of exportCollectionBasedBindings, but no objects are in the collections
cmds.mayaUSDExport( exportCollectionBasedBindings=True, exportMaterialCollections=True, file=usdFilePath,materialCollectionsPath='/Mtl' )
gives the same result that the previous, collections exist but empty
How can I properly export a USD file with material collections assigned ?
thank you

updating maya-usd plugin to 0.30 fixed the problem
